# How to visually match the perspective projection of a Bézier curve to the original, only projecting its control points?

Tags: 3d, projection, perspective, curve, bezier

I am coding a cubic Bézier curve editor that is designed to let you create, select and modify Bézier curves in a 3D world.

I am currently working on the selection/picking interface. I would like to be able to pick the curve based on how far (in terms of pixel count) the user clicked from the actual projected representation of the curve in screen space.

My first approach was to do a brute force numerical analysis in 3D using the segment of the picking ray cast from the camera origin that intersects with the bounding box of the curve cubic segment. I used a dichotomy search to find an approximation of the closest point to the ray on the curve.
It worked, but lacked robustness in use cases and also required the *selection distance* setting to be scaled according to the distance between the camera and the point on the curve. Also it was not an elegant-enough implementation to me. ;)

My current idea is to project the curve segment manually on the near plane, to get a projected Bézier curve that I could perform my numerical analysis on. Also the previous picking ray parameter would now be reduced to a single point: where the user clicked on the viewport.

Unfortunately what I feared before prototyping revealed itself to be true: the projection of a Bézier curve on a plane is not exactly the curve obtained by  the projection of its control points. After further reading on the subject (I am terrible at maths in general), it seems like the projected curve somehow degenerates to a *rational* Bézier curve which is expressed differently.
The visual representation of the new curve does not match the original, it looks fairly close but I need a pixel-perfect match.

I have other options to explore for my problem, like projecting a picking **cone** in the scene, or projecting the curve segment once discretized as a *poly-line*. I would like to know though, whether it exists a quick and easy solution to my current problem through re-parameterization or changes to the projected curve using math tricks I am unable to figure out myself.

Thanks in advance.

**edit** example projection image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4g3u.png

Comment: why is that a problem, though? The projection of a 3D bezier onto a 2D plane gives you a rational Bezier curve that you can use for point-to-curve distance checking. Isn't that what you were trying to do? (effectively: what makes you apprehensive about using the rational form for checking a coordinate is near the projceted curve?)

Comment: Mike, maybe the way I explained it was inexact and misleading: the curve I currently use is the rational Bézier defined by the projection of the original (the one in the 3D scene) curve's control points. It turns out that this new curve does not match the actual projection of all the points of the original curve, which I have no idea whether it can be described in terms of Bézier parameters. I need to be able to reconstruct an exact representation of the curve as it appears on screen so I can check the positions of the points against the position of the cursor for mouse picking.

Comment: This is an example image (I cannot add it to the main post due to lack of reputation): http://i.imgur.com/1XawRof.png . The green curve is the original curve and the red one is the curve described by the projection of the control points onto the near plane.

Comment: added the link to your post for you, although it's hard to tell why the curve is projected the way it is; would it be possible for you to describe that curve as the set of x/y/z coordinates for the curve points, the 2d plane you're projecting onto, and the 2d coordinates that your projected curve then has? It might also simply be a matter of the projection code having (a) bug(s), so some code that shows how you do your projection might be useful too.

Comment: Indeed that is what I am doing now as a fallback: evaluate the 3D curve and project it on the near plane as a poly-line. It works fine and as expected matches the original curve exactly. I hoped to find a way to evaluate the rational curve instead though. About the projection code, I wouldn't vouch for it with my life (as I'm not its author ;) ) but I am pretty confident that it works correctly. By the way, thank you for adding the picture to my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projecting the control points of a Bezier curve onto the near plane by using the appropriate view matrix should yield a rational Bezier curve that is the same as what you see in the viewport.

The problem could stem from a number of issues.  If it were my code, here is what I would try:

- Make sure that the projection to the plane is done properly.  You need to use the world to near plane perspective projection matrix, rather than just projecting the input bezier control points to the view plane.  The perspective projection part of the matrix is what makes polynomial control points turn rational.
- You could create a 3d polyline and project the polyline to your near plane via the perspective matrix.  Your polyline points should be rational, and should exactly match what you see visually (although for a polyine, rational points don't change the rendering at all).  This is a good way to check that your projection is working properly.
- Make sure that your rational curve evaluation is working properly.  A good way to do this is to render a rational circular arc in 2d and make sure that the output points are exactly circular.  I'd do this numerically to avoid any confusion with projection/viewing.

---

So, there are a few different ways you can evaluate a rational Bezier curve.  My favorite way is to evaluate using the simple equation, but on a homogeneous point type, but I've seen people who sum the weights separately, or who evaluate by multiplying the control points by a basis matrix.  Whatever works, I guess.

Here's a good test for 2d rational curve evaluation.  Let's start with an arc, centered on the origin.  We'll use a degree-2 rational Bezier.  The points will be stored as [xw, yw, w].

The three points are:

P0 = [ 1, 0, 1 ], P1 = [ 0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107 ], P2 = [ 0, 1, 1 ]

where 0.707107 is actually sqrt(2)/2

If we evaluate this at t=0.5, we get P = [ 0.603553, 0.603553, 0.853553 ]

If we divide out w, then we get P = [ 0.707107, 0.707107, 1 ]

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: tfinniga, I double-checked the projection code and it seems to be doing what it is expected to. As a fallback, I currently use your second suggestion to implement 3D picking : in the near plane, the code computes the projection of the mouse position against each segment of the projected poly-line. I am confused about your third dot though: so far I evaluated the rational ('projected') curve exactly the same way as the original curve. The only difference is that it is done in 2D space with 2D vectors. Should that process yield the exact same curve?

Comment: I'll edit my answer with more details on rational curve evaluation, I was getting a bit cramped in the comment.. ;)

Comment: Oh, I'm starting to get it, thanks! Would you know how to retrieve the respective weights I have to apply to the projected control points to obtain the same shape as the original curve?

Comment: So, your world-to-screen matrix is going to be a 4x4 matrix.  Your control points are 3d points, but you can express them as homogeneous points with w=1: [x, y, z, 1].  Multiply that by your 4x4 matrix, and you will get a homogeneous point [xw, yw, zw, w].  That will be in your screen space, just use [xw, yw, w].

Comment: Oh ok I never thought *that* w would be relevant for the evaluation of the projected curve! Thank you very much. I will test this ASAP, then post the results and accept you answer.